# Cordova start app very slow

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I build an app with cordova. The app itself is very fast. 
But the start of the app(the time from the click on the button till the first screen shows ) it more then 8 sec.

How can I make it faster?? I know that many apps wrote with cordova and I dont think that it take 8 sec for those apps.

I dont need any feature of cordova only internet access and show the page. no camera no permissions..

Thanks

Comment: Are you including external libraries such as jQuery*, Bootstrap etc? If so, I would suggest storing them locally in your JS / css folders.

Comment: @Alon, Agree with andre3wap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping all the sources locally also won't help you much.

You have two options

1. Minimize all the source js and CSS files . This will work for smaller js and CSS files.
2. For larger js and CSS use **lazy loading**. In this load as few resources as possible at start of app. Later whenever is required load other resources.

Consider one more thing, create a single page web application. Switching from one page to another during app execution gives a bad user experience.

Comment: I found my problem. I use polymer and it loads like 100 files. I think if I will merge all the file to one file it will help. And also I have fonts that I load from google and it make like 4 request for this fonts, from the google server and it take somthing like 500ms. I will try to download this fonts to local.

Comment: Good you found solution