# Cordova jquery mobile app slow

Tags: jquery, cordova, mobile

The first page of my app is a splash one because I need to make two ajax calls before running de app.

The first call checks if the user is already logged, while the second one get some data to display on google maps.

My problem is that the splash screen has a blue background and when I open it on an android phone, it renders half blue, half white. After one second (more or less), the page shows totally blue.

After this splash page and all the data is acquired from server, the app make a slide transition to the page with the map. This slide transition is the moment I mean, as you can't see the slide effect. In some cases you can see it, but laggy.

How could I fix this?

Comment: Your chances to get an answer will be considerable increased if you attach some code of your App (where you believe the problem is) and, eventually, you upload a video with the wrong behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

see this answer of mine, it will help you to speed up cordova app performance [Cordova start app very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32772276/cordova-start-app-very-slow/32793149#32793149)